# Changing InnerHTML with a helper method in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to rails, and I have a website already that has a js function that uses the `onchange` method with `<select>`. The code is kind of like this:

`var text = document.getElementById("dude");`

`text.innerHTML = "bro";`

The thing is, I want to rewrite everything in Ruby.
Is there a way to use anything like a helper method to pass an argument and change the value of html?

`<p><%= text = "hey" %></p>`

`<% helper_method(text) %>`

I've been looking around for an answer and saw RJS? Not sure if this is related, but I just don't really know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: An `onchange` handler is executed in the browser to provide interactivity *without* contacting the server. Attempting to rewrite that in Ruby doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

The big problem you have is that you're confusing the roles of `Ruby` & `JS`.

Ruby is a server-side language; it runs *on the server* to compile pure HTML for your browser. This HTML is passed to your front-end client (browser), where it is then rendered.

--

`Ruby == PHP` -- it cannot interactively change elements after the "DOM" has loaded. Javascript *can*, and is why you'll not be able to fully translate your code into JS.

The *only* way to capture `onchange` (events) is to use JS / JQuery to handle them:

```
onchange="return js_function();"
```

> `(Java)Scripts` are embedded in or included from `HTML` pages and interact with the [`Document Object Model (DOM)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) of the page

Ruby can only do this when the HTML is rendered on the server. JS is currently the only way to bind events to elements.... *however* the way you interpret those events can harness ruby.

---

**Ajax**

Using [**`Ajax`** (`Asynchronous Javascript and XML`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) allows you to send requests to your server, appending the result into the DOM. The server-side processing *would* induce Ruby, allowing you to use it to provide the most appropriate response:

```
#HTML
<%= link_to "x", "path", onchange: "return js_function();" %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
function js_function() {
   var value = // ajax //
   var text = document.getElementById("dude");
   text.innerHTML = value;
}
```

I don't know what you're trying to do; using `Ajax` with pure JS is pretty difficult; `JQuery` has its own [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function to handle it for you if you wish (to drink from the devil's cup):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
function js_function() {
   var value = $.get("your/path");
   var text = document.getElementById("dude");
   text.innerHTML = value;
}

#config/routes.rb
resources :your do
  get :path, on: :collection
end

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def path
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render text: "TESTER" }
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so helpful. I've never really gotten into server side, I've only made some basic stuff with using a form to send information to a .php file, nothing really with databases, so this was really helpful. Thanks so much for the info!

Comment: No problem; Rails is a completely different kettle of fish to PHP, you should definitely look at getting experience with it to know how it works etc

Answer (score 0):

ruby code do get executed on browser. Writing your code in ruby will ultimately generate the javascript code then get executed on browser.

And if you want the value to be populated on server response then you need to hook server hit and the modify the value on the basis of the response. And this all needs to be done in javascript.